# Display vertical line on intersection point

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to represent a **Pareto** chart with Highcharts, as you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/NelsonReis/yr779/).
The horizontal line shows the **80% value**, but now I wanted to display a vertical line where that horizontal 80% line intersects with the "Acumulated" chart series.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Another option would be to get the "x" value of the "Acumulated" spline where it's "y" value is "80", that way I could then draw the line manually.
Is this even possible with the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)?

I know that it's possible to get the values of a point in a series, but that isn't enough in this case:

```
var point = chart.get('accumulated').data[2];
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for  that.I am facing same issue.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN It was awhile ago, but I don't think I could, sorry. If you manage to find a solution, please add it as an answer.

Comment: yes,I have find it using basic mathematics formla

Answer (score 1):

I have find it for 80:20 calculation.

First I have find the first value in series from Spline data  which greater than or equal to 80.

```
i.e. >= 80
```

Suppose it is `DataX`
Then find out the that index in array plus one for `DataX`.

`i.e. DataX location is  DataIndex = index+1`

(as array start from 0th calculation need plus one)

formula is
`DataX : DataIndex  :: 80: ?`

```
let the question mark is xIndexOf80
```

then xIndexOf80 = (DataIndex  *80)/(DataX ).

```
xIndexOf80 is nothing but position of 80 on X axis.
```

which gives  you exact marks on X-Axis

```
function findInetrSectionPoint(arrSplineData) {

    var intLen = arrSplineData.length;

    for (var index = 0; index < intLen; index++) {

      if (arrSplineData[index] >= 80) {

        interSectPoint = ((index + 1) * 80) / arrSplineData[index] - 1;
        break;
      }

    }

    return interSectPoint;
  }
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IGvgzYHiLCRJExUdgTco?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate position of 80% point and then use http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer rect. Apart from that you can also check this option http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotLine() / http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.plotLines

Comment: The big question here is how can I calculate the "x" position when the "y" is 80% ?

Comment: You can calculate your position based on chart plot area pixels. http://jsfiddle.net/yr779/4/

Comment: Thanks for the help, Sebastian. Maybe I didn't explain myself very well. When I say "80%" I mean that value in the "Accumulated" series (the dark red spline), so that I can draw a vertical line when it intersects with the horizontal green dashed line. Your example displays a vertical line at 80% of the available chart width. Am I wrong?