# Highcharts - Adding a vertical line at specific y axis value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts, I am trying to add a vertical line (not horizontal) at a specific Y Axis value. I dont know the corresponding x-axis point/value.

Please find the example in the link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8kLK/24/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'column',
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'#ccc',
    marginLeft:110,
    marginRight:50,
    backgroundColor:'#eee',
    plotBackgroundColor:'#fff',
    alignTicks:false,
},
title:{
    text:'Pareto Test 2'
},
legend:{

},
tooltip:{
    formatter:function(){
            if(this.series.name == 'Cumulative Percent'){
                return this.y + '%';
            }
            return this.y;
        }
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        shadow:false,
    }
},
xAxis:{
    categories:['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickLength:3,
    title:{
        text:'X Axis Title',
        style:{
            color:'#000'
        }
    }
},
yAxis:[{
    endOnTick:false,
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickWidth:1,
    tickLength:3,
    gridLineColor:'#ddd',
    title:{
        text:'Y Axis Title',
        rotation:0,
        margin:50,
        style:{
            color:'#000'
        }
    }
},{
    title:{text:''},
    gridLineWidth:0,
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickWidth:1,
    tickLength:3,
    endOnTick:false,
    opposite:true,
    min:0,
    labels:{
        formatter:function(){
            return this.value + '%';
        }
    }
}],
series: [{
    name:'Values',
    yAxis:0,
    data: [515,475,360,255,245,230,120,115],
},{
    type:'line',
    name:'Cumulative Percent',
    yAxis:1,
    data: [28,46,60,73,84,91,96,100],
}]
```

});

In the example above, i would like to add a vertical line at say 73% or 84% markers (or at any y axis point on line). How would i do that? Please help me.

Comment: You can calculate point and use [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines) / [addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine)

Comment: Thanks for reply. My requirement is to create a VERTICAL plot line or any line using ONLY Y-Axis value. All these example show using x-axis. If you could give me an example, it would be great.

Comment: How would it know where on the xAxis to plot this vertical line based on a yAxis value? Do you have an example of what you want?

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense as stated. Where do you need to draw the line? This is a 2D space, which requires 2 values to draw within...

Comment: In my requirement, i can calculate only Y axis value for which i am not sure what the corresponding x value is. In my fiddle example, i have values like 28,46,60,73,84,91,96,100 and i want to draw a vertical line at say 80% for which i dont know the corresponding x value. Is there anyway of doing it?

Comment: My requirement is almost similar like in this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812821/display-vertical-line-on-intersection-point

Comment: You can get min and max point, then calcualte difference and multiply by 0.8. As a result you achieve value which is  80% of existed points.